# Using after filter modifies the response code to 200 OK

Tags: spark-java

I declared a path /api. It has currently 1 route /person (get). Up to now, if I attempted to get /api/whatever-that-is-not-person, the server would return 404 which is exactly what you would expect.
However, I added an after filter, and now it systematically returns 200 for routes that don't exist.

Removing the after filter, it works fine as expected. Important to know that while the after modifies the body of the response, it doesn't go anywhere near modifying the status.

See minimal reproducible example below. In the example I just add an empty JSON object to the body, but of course in the real application I am doing something else, but not modifying the status code.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;
import spark.servlet.SparkApplication;
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Server implements SparkApplication {

    private static org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Server.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Server().init();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {

        before("*", (request, response) -> {
            LOGGER.info("Request: " + request.url());
        });

        after((request, response) -> {
            response.type("application/json");
            response.header("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

        });

        /**
         * Let's declare routes
         */
        get("/ping", Server.ping);

        path("/api", () -> {
            //add query information to response object
            after("/*", (Request request, Response response) -> {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

                JsonObject body;
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    body = new JsonParser().parse(response.body()).getAsJsonObject();
                } else {
                    body = new JsonObject();
                }

                response.body(body.toString());
            });

            get("/person", Server.ping);
        });

    public static Route ping = (Request req, Response res) -> {
        res.status(200);
        return "Alive.";
    };
}
```

If you undeclare the after filter in /api, everything works fine and only /api/person will return 200. I expect that with the filter, if the route doesn't exist, then the status is 404.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
   after("/*", (Request request, Response response) -> {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

            JsonObject body;
            if (response.body() != null) {
                body = new JsonParser().parse(response.body()).getAsJsonObject();
            } else {
                body = new JsonObject();
            }

            response.body(body.toString());
        });
```

in after filter remove the wildcard.

```
   after("/", (Request request, Response response) -> {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

            JsonObject body;
            if (response.body() != null) {
                body = new JsonParser().parse(response.body()).getAsJsonObject();
            } else {
                body = new JsonObject();
            }

            response.body(body.toString());
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, this is not helping. If I remove the wildcard, while it does return 404, it also doesn't apply the filter.